# Counting the number of occurrences of unknown number of inputs

Tags: java, arrays, loops, arraylist

I am unable to stop taking the input from the user. An infinite loop is being created and I am not sure what my conditions should be or if the entire program in wrong.

I am trying to create a program where the user enters integers in the first line separated by space and in the next line gives the integer that he/she wants to count the occurrence of.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Pracitce {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        int count = 0;
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        while(n != '\n'){
            
            num.add(n);
            n = scan.nextInt();
        }
        Integer second = scan.nextInt();

        int arr[] = new int[num.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i<num.size();i++){
            arr[i] = num.get(i);
        }
        for(int i: arr){
            if(second == i){
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }

}
```

Expected output:
1 2 2 3 3 3 3
3
4

Answer (score 2):

`nextInt()` gives no indication of whether the next line was reached or not. You could instead read one line with `Scanner#nextLine`, then `split` it on a space, and finally parse each part into an int.

For example:

```java
String[] strs = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
int[] nums = new int[strs.length];
for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++)
    nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(strs[i]);
int search = scan.nextInt();
int count = 0;
for (int x : nums)
    if (x == search)
        ++count;
System.out.println(count);
```

There is a built-in method, `Collections.frequency`, that can count occurrences of a value, so this can be simplified.

```java
var nums = Arrays.stream(scan.nextLine().split(" ")).map(Integer::valueOf).toList();
int search = scan.nextInt();
int count = Collections.frequency(nums, search);
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Using method nextLine(), you can get whole line of input as a String.
2. Once you got the String, you can convert this string to array, by using split(" ") method.
3. And after getting int for which we will be counting its occurrence, we can loop through the str array, and try to convert each el to Num, but since user could mess up with input, we can use try catch block so it would just skip non convertible elements, without throwing any error.

For Example:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please enter numbers separated by space");
String[] strArr = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

System.out.println("Which numbers occurrence you would like to count?");
int numToSearch = scanner.nextInt();

int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    try {
        if (Integer.parseInt(strArr[i]) == numToSearch) count++;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
}
System.out.println("Number " + numToSearch + "'s occurrence is: " + count);
```